# How to process huge Apache log file using python

Tags: python, pandas, apache, logging

I have a CSV file that contains a column called `click_id`, and I want to use this `click_id` to search a large Apache log file (around 3GB) for the corresponding log entries. When a matching log entry is found, I need to extract the user agent and other information from the log entry. I would also like to group and count similar log entries and write the results to another CSV file.

What is the most efficient and reliable way to accomplish this task in Python?  What is the best way to handle the large size of the log file and ensure that the script runs efficiently without running out of memory or causing other performance issues?

This is what I have tried but its been 3 days and it is still running.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from user_agents import parse

clickid_list = []
device_list = []


with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        # check if click_id column is not blank or null
        if row[29] != "" and row[29] != "null" and row[29] != "click_id":
            clickid_list.append(row[29])

matched_lines_count = defaultdict(int)


def log_file_generator(filename, chunk_size=200 * 1024 * 1024):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        while True:
            chunk = file.readlines(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            yield chunk

for chunk in log_file_generator('data.log'):
    for line in chunk:
        for gclid in clickid_list:
            if gclid in line:
                string = "'" + str(line) + "'"
                user_agent = parse(string)
                device = user_agent.device.family
                device_brand = user_agent.device.brand
                device_model = user_agent.device.model
                os = user_agent.os.family
                os_version = user_agent.os.version
                browser= user_agent.browser.family
                browser_version= user_agent.browser.version

                if device in matched_lines_count:
                    matched_lines_count[device]["count"] += 1
                    print(matched_lines_count[device]["count"])
                else:
                    matched_lines_count[device] = {"count": 1, "os": os,"os_version": os_version,"browser": browser,"browser_version": browser_version,"device_brand": device_brand,"device_model": device_model}

# sort garne 
sorted_matched_lines_count = sorted(matched_lines_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['count'], reverse=True)

with open("test_op.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows([["Device", "Count", "OS","OS version","Browser","Browser version","device_brand","device model"]])

        for line, count in sorted_matched_lines_count:
            # if count['count'] >= 20:
            # print(f"Matched Line: {line} | Count: {count['count']} | OS: {count['os']}")
            # write the data to a CSV file
                writer.writerow([line,count['count'],count['os'],count['os_version'],count['browser'],count['browser_version'],count['device_brand'],count['device_model']])
```

Example of log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2022:06:50:20 +0000] "GET /access?click_id=12345678925455 HTTP/1.1" 200 39913 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A107F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2022:06:50:22 +0000] "GET /access?click_id=123456789 HTTP/1.1" 200 39914 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A705FN) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Result expected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PySpark, then you have big date. also then you reduce date can use Pandas. PySpark is similar then Pandas.

```
#pandas
 pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv')

#pyspark
spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]")
          .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
          .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")
df.printSchema()
```